# Cant load mailgun class from vendor

Tags: php, model-view-controller, composer-php, mailgun

I have created a custom php mvc pattern and i am trying to load mailgun which was installed using composer in my project but i am getting a failed to open stream: No such file or directory error and i cant resolve it

This is my page structure

[image: My page structure]

**Public/index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../app/bootstrap.php');

 // Init Core Library
 $init = new Core;
```

**app/libraries/core.php**
This is the main app core class which creates url and loads core controllers and to create a clean url format

```
<?php

 class Core {
// Set Defaults
protected $currentController = 'Pages'; // Default controller
protected $currentMethod = 'index'; // Default method
protected $params = []; // Set initial empty params array

public function __construct(){
  $url = $this->getUrl();
  // Look in controllers folder for controller
  if(file_exists('../app/controllers/'.ucwords($url[0]).'.php')){
    // If exists, set as controller
    $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
    // Unset 0 index
    unset($url[0]);
  }

  // Require the current controller
  require_once('../app/controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php');

  // Instantiate the current controller
  $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

  // Check if second part of url is set (method)
  if(isset($url[1])){
    // Check if method/function exists in current controller class
    if(method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])){
      // Set current method if it exsists
      $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
      // Unset 1 index
      unset($url[1]);
    }
  }

  // Get params - Any values left over in url are params
  $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

  // Call a callback with an array of parameters
  call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);
}

// Construct URL From $_GET['url']
public function getUrl(){
    if(isset($_GET['url'])){
      $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
      $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
      $url = explode('/', $url);
      return $url;
    }
}
}
```

**app/libraries/mail.php**

```
<?php
 use Mailgun\Mailgun;
 class Mail
  {

 public  function send($to, $subject, $text, $html)
  {

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'verify' => false,
    ]);
    $adapter = new Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client($client);

    $mg = new Mailgun(Config::MAILGUN_API_KEY, $adapter);
    $domain = Config::MAILGUN_DOMAIN;

    $mg->sendMessage($domain, ['from'    => 'test@test.com',
                               'to'      => $to,
                               'subject' => $subject,
                               'text'    => $text,
                               'html'    => $html]);

  }

}
```

**app/bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

// Load Config
require_once 'config/config.php';


 // Load Config
require_once 'config.php';

 //Load Vendor

require_once 'libraries/vendor/autoload.php';




// Autoload Core Libraries
 spl_autoload_register(function($className){
 require_once 'libraries/' . $className . '.php';
});
```

**App/controllers/Pages.php**

```
<?php

class Pages extends Controller{


public function __construct(){

     $this->shopModel = $this->model('Shop');
 }


 // Load Homepage
public function index(){


$mail = new  Mail();
$send = $mail->send('john_644@hotmail.com','test','this is 
test','<h1>this is test</h1>');

$this->view('shops/index' , $data); 
 }

}
```

I have created a config class which is in the app root (App/config.php) it holds the mailgun api key and the domain name, that will be called in the mail class located in the libraries folder.The composer.json file is located in the libraries folder

[image: error message]

Comment: Your autoloader is incorrect - you should check if file actually exist before `require_once`.

Comment: i have tried `function my_autoloader($class) {
  if(file_exists('libraries/'.$class.'.php')){
    require 'libraries/' .$class.'.php';
  }  
}


spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');`  but i am getting **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Core' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\vlake\public\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\vlake\public\index.php on line 5**

Comment: Please share all error messages in text form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your auto load function in the bootstrap.php, because composer already creates an auto load function all you need to do is call the vendor autoload.php

remove the

```
// Autoload Core Libraries
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
require_once 'libraries/' . $className . '.php';
 });
```

And add this it will work

```
<?php

 // Load Config
  require_once 'config/config.php';

 // Load Config
require_once 'config.php';

//Load Vendor
require_once 'libraries/vendor/autoload.php'; 
require_once 'libraries/Core.php';
require_once 'libraries/Mail.php';
```